# Check email availability while typing

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm trying to basically check whether a typed email is already registered or not, on the spot.
Trying to make that(An example to what I wish to do in the link, can't upload images):

http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-2gcqeLxtuOs/UTxEge1d9XI/AAAAAAAAAz8/79M9RyYRHZs/s1600/UserAvailability.gif

And I don't seem to understand what's wrong with my code, probably lack od knowledge or overlooking something. My code:


Register.aspx:

```
 function UserChecker(username) {

     lbl = document.getElementById('<%=Label2.ClientID %>');

     if (username == '') {
         lbl.innerHTML = 'Please Enter a User Name';
         lbl.style.color = "black";

     }
     else {

         PageMethods.UserNameChecker(username, OnSucceeded);
     }
 }

 function OnSucceeded(result, userContext, methodName)
  {

      lbl = document.getElementById('<%=Label2.ClientID %>');

      if (methodName == "UserNameChecker")
      {

          if (result == true)
          {
              lbl.innerHTML = 'User name not available';
              lbl.style.color = "red";
          }

          else
           {
              lbl.innerHTML = 'User name available';
              lbl.style.color = "green";
          }


     }


 }
```

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="User Name"></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <asp:TextBox ID="email" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" onkeyup="UserChecker(this.value)" style="font-size: 20px; text-align:center; border-radius: 20px;" class="RegisterButton" ValidationGroup="registergroup" placeholder="What's your Email?"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Register.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;

using System.Web.Services;

public partial class CheckUserAvailability : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    [WebMethod]
    public static bool UserNameChecker(string UserName)
    {

        if (WebUser.IsUserNameExist(UserName) == true)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

WebUser.cs(A class I created):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;

//Get the username if the entered user name is in the table.

public class WebUser
{

    public static bool IsUserNameExist(string UserName)
    {
        OleDbConnection objConnUser = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") + @"\App_Data\Database.accdb" + "");
        objConnUser.Open();

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        OleDbParameter objParam = new OleDbParameter();
        OleDbCommand objCmd = new OleDbCommand("CheckOnSpot", objConnUser);
        objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        objParam = new OleDbParameter("@UserName", OleDbType.Char);
        objParam.Value = UserName;
        objCmd.Parameters.Add(objParam);

        if (objCmd.ExecuteScalar() != null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

UsersInfo.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;


    public class UsersInfo
    {
        public int UserID;
        public string firstname;
        public string email;
        public string password;
        public string lastname;
        public int age;
        public string phonenumber;
        public string picture;

        public UsersInfo()
        {

        }

    }
```

CheckOnSpot query(Just if it'll be needed anyhow):

```
SELECT email
FROM users
WHERE email = [@UserName];
```

Thanks in advance. Hope you'll see what I missed.

Comment: You need to use jquery ajax. On keyup event call server sided method and depending on result retrieved show message.

Answer (score 0):

ASPX  ADD :  OnTextChanged="email_TextChanged"

```
<asp:TextBox ID="email" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" onkeyup="UserChecker(this.value)" style="font-size: 20px; text-align:center; border-radius: 20px;" class="RegisterButton" ValidationGroup="registergroup" placeholder="What's your Email?"  ></asp:TextBox>
```

CODE BEHIND :

```
      protected void email_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string email= email.Text;

            string conStr;
            conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cnSting_Con"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
            con.Open();
            // WRITE STORED PROCEDURE TO CHECK EMAIl ID 
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("CheckEmailExist  ", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@email", email));

            DataTable ds = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter sd = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            sd.Fill(ds);
            con.Close();
```

STORED PROCEDURE : Write Procedure [CheckEmailExist]

Comment: I'm having hard time trying to figure out what you did here. Would you mind explain, please? Also I don't reach the SQL the way you do, which make errors for me.

Comment: On text change event find whether email id exist or not. If exist then write your code what you want. In your case don't return datatable, it will return int and then write your code what you want